# Did + verb instead verb + ed

Tags: past-tense

In one dialogue in a computer game, I've seen a sentence, "I did steal it!" instead of "I stole it!". Why can native speakers use I did + verb instead of verb + ed?

Comment: Did is used in situations where you really want to emphasize that you really did perform the action.  If someone doubts that you stole something, you can say, "I did steal it".

Comment: Or it could be an example of what’s called ‘Local colour’, where the writer uses incorrect grammar to make a point about a character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a special privilege of native speakers. One of the functions of "do" as an auxiliary verb is as an intensifier.

> I do study hard

is an emphatic statement about my studying.

I suppose as a purely technical matter you could replace every simple past tense with "did" plus the root verb without violating the rules of English grammar. No native speaker, however, does so because if you emphasize everything, you emphasize nothing.